# how to instal mongodb php driver on windows 8 and wamp server?

Tags: php, mongodb, pecl, nosql

I am trying to instal mongodb driver in php. I am using wamp server with php version 5.5.12. I have tried it alot but don't know what am I doing wrong. Here is what I did:

Step 1: I downloaded the mongodb driver package from this link: 
        http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo/1.5.5/windows
        I downloaded 5.5 Non Thread Safe (NTS) x64 under PHP 5.5 tab.

Step 2: I unzipped the downloaded file and copied the php_mongo.dll and php_mongo.pdb files into C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext

Step 3: I included this line 'extension=php_mongo.dll' in my php.ini file.

Step 4: I restarted the wamp server.

After doing all this, I am still not able to locate PHP Mongo in localhost/php.info which means the driver has not installed. I badly need some help. please tell me step by step how can I instal mongodb php driver on windows?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it..all I did was copied the libsasl.dll file from 'C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12' and paste it into 'C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin'.

Answer (score 0):

DLL name must be same as you given in php.ini extension=php_mongo.dll
the extension you given line must not start with ; 
it must be like following.
extension=php_mongo.dll
this(;) is used for comment.
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.x\ext\
I got the same problem and fixed it when I removed ;

if you still face the problem I'll resolve it... just comment...

Comment: I have not used (;) with extension extension=php_mongo.dll. and my file names are also same (php_mongo.dll). but it is still not working for me.

Comment: If you have done every thing correctly then there might be problem in installing mongoDB. just check in command line IS mongo db is installed or not.
Can you check there?

Comment: I have installed mongodb correctly. I have developed few databases and collections and everything is fine. there is no issue with the installtion of mongodb