# Install phpMongo Drivers on windows

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to run mongodb from PHP 5.6. I have downloaded it from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library. I run the command `composer require "mongodb/mongodb=^1.0.0"` and what about the `zip` file? Is there any easy method to install it?

I run this code

```
<?php
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';
 $connection = new MongoDB();

?>
```

and getting error:

> Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB' not found in C:\wamp64\www\

```
new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

works fine but for saving the document `$collection->insert($document);` gives the error `insert method is not found`

Comment: It is not needed to download it yourself. Composer wil download the version you need and 'install' it for you. That means: place the files in the vendor map, and generate an autoload.php you'll have to include in your project.

Comment: I have added it. But still giving the error. See the udated question.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to ask a totaly new question in the one that has just been answered.. Ignoring that: what do you get if you do echo get_class($collection) ?

Comment: i haven't tried to install it with composer but manually on wamp server and i had problems with the drivers for windows on W10 and W8.1. i tried older verions, 1.5.2 worked for me, but that was a year ago

Comment: @Marko Kindly tell me the way, where I get the solution of this problem.

Comment: @Amar for wamp you can find an answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295351/how-to-instal-mongodb-php-driver-on-windows-8-and-wamp-server), don't know how to install a different version of mongodb drivers the composer way, sorry

Comment: @Marko Its the problem that the driver is not installed. I have installed the driver. `phpinfo()` is showing `mongo`. But I think I am using wrong library. But unable to figure it. What should I use.

Comment: @11mb it is your kindness that you are ignoring it. I get `MongoDB\Collection` by running 'echo get_class($collection)`.

Comment: In future, please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the files are in the vendor map the installation via composer went probably well. I think the problem now is that you want to create an instance of a class that doesn't exist. Isn't MongoDB the namespace and not the class?

From the documentation of MongoDB:

```
$database = (new MongoDB\Client)->selectDatabase('db_name');
```

See the documentation on namespaces: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

-edit-

For inserting you should use `insertOne()` according to the documentation: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/classes/collection/#insertone

```
function insertOne($document, array $options = []): MongoDB\InsertOneResult
```

Comment: `new MongoDB\Client` works fine but for saving the document `$collection->insert($document);` gives the error `insert methid is not found`

Comment: Nice! Good to hear you got something working! I think this would be a new question :). I don't have experience with MongoDb.

Comment: I updated my answer. Maybe you are using the documentation on php.net? and not the documentation from github?

Comment: Mannnnnnnnnnnnn.. You made my day. Literally. God Bless you.